# Can I make a local function inside the constructor and call it

Tags: c#, function, constructor

If I do this

```
class CommandBuilder
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string NewText { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public CommandBuilder(string action, string id, string newtext, string type)
    {
        Action = action;
        ID = id;
        NewText = newtext;
        Type = type;
        DataFormatter Build()
        {
            Command cmd2 = new Command(Commands.CommandsEnum.Run);
            DataFormatter df2 = new DataFormatter();
            df2._Command = cmd2;
            Subcommand scmd2 = new Subcommand();
            scmd2.Action = Action;
            scmd2.ID = ID;
            scmd2.NewValueString = NewText;
            scmd2.Type = Type;
            df2._Subcommand = scmd2;
            return df2;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use the code, can I simply make an instance of CommandBuilder and call .Build() after it 
like:

```
new CommandBuilder(action, id, newtext, type).Build()
```

is my intention to be able to use.
Or to make a method called same way after constructor
method(parameters).build()
It is important to me that it is on one line

Comment: Why not make a proper instance method out of it?

Comment: A **local** function is **local within the member where it is defined**. So, no, you can´t call a local function outside its declaring scope.

Comment: You could call it if you returned it from a normal method through a delegate, but the syntax would be `obj.SomeMethod(...)()` (the last pair of parentheses there is for the call to the delegate.) But no, as @HimBromBeere states, a local function is local within its declaring scope.

Comment: The constructor of `CommandBuilder` can only return a CommandBuilder, not a DataFormatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use the builder pattern
[Wikipedia link to builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

This is my end code that allows me to use it how I wanted it to
like:

> CommandBuilder.WithAction("action").Build("Command");

like that

```
public class CommandBuilder
{
    public class internalCommandBuilder
    {
        private string Action = "";
        private string ID = "";
        private string NewText = "";
        private string Type = "";
        private Commands.CommandsEnum enumResult;

        public internalCommandBuilder WithAction(string action)
        {
            Action = action;
            return this;
        }

        public internalCommandBuilder WithID(string id)
        {
            ID = id;
            return this;
        }

        public internalCommandBuilder WithNewText(string newText)
        {
            NewText = newText;
            return this;
        }

        public internalCommandBuilder WithType(string type)
        {
            Type = type;
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Todo: document this
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="command"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public DataFormatter Build(string command)
        {
            Enum.TryParse<Commands.CommandsEnum>(command, out enumResult);
            Command cmd2 = new Command(enumResult);
            DataFormatter df2 = new DataFormatter();
            df2._Command = cmd2;
            Subcommand scmd2 = new Subcommand();
            scmd2.Action = Action;
            scmd2.ID = ID;
            scmd2.NewValueString = NewText;
            scmd2.Type = Type;
            df2._Subcommand = scmd2;
            Action = "";
            ID = "";
            NewText = "";
            Type = "";
            return df2;
        }
    }
    public static internalCommandBuilder WithAction(string action)
    {
        return new internalCommandBuilder().WithAction(action);
    }

    public static internalCommandBuilder WithID(string id)
    {
        return new internalCommandBuilder().WithID(id);
    }

    public static internalCommandBuilder WithNewText(string newText)
    {
        return new internalCommandBuilder().WithNewText(newText);
    }

    public static internalCommandBuilder WithType(string type)
    {
        return new internalCommandBuilder().WithType(type);
    }

    public CommandBuilder()
    {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
new CommandBuilder(action, id, newtext, type).Build()
```

if you define the method inside the class and call it right after construction.

.NET does not allow you to define class methods inside constructors.

Comment: ".NET does not allow you to define class methods inside constructors." That´s not true. Local functions (that´s what OP is after and that were introduced in C#7) can also be defined in a constructor, see https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions.

Comment: Not entirely true. I was referring to class methods instead of local functions, because of the syntax that OP described as needed. He could define the function inside the constructor and store it in a field as well, but that’s not what I gathered from the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not what *local* functions are for. If you want to call a method on an instance of a class, it needs to be a function defined for instances of that class with the correct visibility (e.g. `public`).

For your code:

```cs
class CommandBuilder
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string NewText { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public CommandBuilder(string action, string id, string newtext, string type)
    {
        Action = action;
        ID = id;
        NewText = newtext;
        Type = type;
    }

    public DataFormatter Build()
    {
        Command cmd2 = new Command(Commands.CommandsEnum.Run);
        DataFormatter df2 = new DataFormatter();
        df2._Command = cmd2;
        Subcommand scmd2 = new Subcommand();
        scmd2.Action = this.Action;
        scmd2.ID = this.ID;
        scmd2.NewValueString = this.NewText;
        scmd2.Type = this.Type;
        df2._Subcommand = scmd2;
        return df2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want method inside constructor. simplest way is to write separate method and call it in constructor

Something like,

```
class CommandBuilder
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string NewText { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public CommandBuilder(string action, string id, string newtext, string type)
    {
        Action = action;
        ID = id;
        NewText = newtext;
        Type = type

    }

    //Separate method, you need to decide access modifier and parameters as per your requirement
    public DataFormatter Build()
    {
        Command cmd2 = new Command(Commands.CommandsEnum.Run);
        DataFormatter df2 = new DataFormatter();
        df2._Command = cmd2;
        Subcommand scmd2 = new Subcommand();
        scmd2.Action = Action;
        scmd2.ID = ID;
        scmd2.NewValueString = NewText;
        scmd2.Type = Type;
        df2._Subcommand = scmd2;
        return df2;
    }
}
```

If you want to use with instance you can use it like,

```
var commandBuilderInstance = new CommandBuilder("action", "id", "newtext", "type");
commandBuilderInstance.Build();
```

If you need one liner solution, (which I believe not a good practice)

```
var dataformatterInstance = new CommandBuilder("action", "id", "newtext", "type").Build();
```

Comment: My intention is to be able to call a method to add the parameters, then call .build right after it like:
method(parameters).build

Comment: Then you can call it in constructor. As I showed in my answer. This will add parameters first and will execute your `Build()` function

Comment: Yes, but I wish to add them and call build on one line of code

Comment: Actually with that code, you can use the code like `var df = new CommandBuilder(...).Build()`. But you probably do not want to call the `Build()` in constructor then

Comment: @anonymousdotnetdeveloper666, Yes I mentioned this in my answer. If needed then call it in constructor. Otherwise we can call it with instance. or `var df = new CommandBuilder(...).Build()`. I updated my answer kindly have a look

Comment: Thank you! A collegue helped me and I have posted an answer detailing what I wanted and how I did it